# wsl ubuntu Temporary failure in name resolution only on my home network

Tags: networking, 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2. When trying to ping google.com, I get the "Temporary failure in name resolution" error, and it might be specifically related to my home network. My wsl.conf and resolv.conf (which I edited as instructed at work) files are:

```
wsl.conf
[network]
generateResolvConf = false

resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 172.20.242.68
nameserver 8.8.8.4
```

I am able to ping 8.8.8.8 directly but trying to ping google.com fails.
The only 2 instances where I have no problems are:

1. If I'm not using my home's internet. For example, if I connect my laptop to my phone's hotspot, everything works as normally.
2. If I'm logged in to my company's Forticlient VPN (even when on my home network)